# Create link to open app from mail without making changes in app

Tags: browser, hyperlink, ios9, mobile-safari, deep-linking

I have an app which is already published in app store, I need to send mail to users with link clicking on which it should open the app if its installed or should go to app store. I'm aware of the URL schemes and universal links and that would require modification in my app. I was wondering if there is any other way that this could be achieved where I could create a link maybe using `itms-app` or some other method where I don't need to make any changes in the app. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. For a phone to open your application, it needs a way to recognize your application.

## **URI Schemes**

The URI scheme information is configured in the `.plist` file and is local to the application and therefore cannot be changed without an update. Although you probably don't want to use URI schemes anyways since they will present the user an error if they don't have the app instead of taking them to the app store.

## **Universal Links**

This is the new way Apple performs deep linking and the only other way a link could open up the app. These require a locally stored entitlements file along with an `.apple-app-site-association` that is hosted on your own website domain and cached when the app is downloaded or updated. These also do not take users to the app store, they take users to the domain in which the AASA file is hosted.

## **Best Solution**

Use [Branch's iOS SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/) to handle all of the AASA file hosting and App Store redirection. This would still require you to push out a new update, but that is the only possible way to accomplish this.